# UILabel text setting causes EXC_BAD_INSTR EXC_i386_INVOP

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uilabel

Currently working on an iOS app in Swift, and I have a UILabel created in Storyboard control click linked to my View Controller, but whenever I try to access and set the text of this label, I get a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. The code is being called from a PFArrayResultBlock, so I'm not sure if it's a self issue, but here is the block I'm using:

```
let block : PFArrayResultBlock = { (array: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if(array.count == 0) {
            self.setupBankInfoViews()
            self.isEnteringBankInfo = true
        } else {
            var credits : String = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("credits") as! String
            var text = "You have "
            text += credits
            text += " credits. Cash out now for XXX dollars"
            self.creditLabel.text = text
            self.isEnteringBankInfo = false
            if(self.routingNumberTextField != nil) {
                self.routingNumberTextField.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            if(self.accountNumberTextField != nil) {
                self.accountNumberTextField.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            self.cashOutButton.setTitle("Cash Out", forState: UIControlState.allZeros)

        }
    }
```

The error seems to be occurring on the line with `self.creditLabel.text = text`, and never gets past that. My `creditLabel` is defined as such:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var creditLabel: UILabel!
```

Not quite sure what's going on here, this code seemed to work a couple days ago and I came back to it today and it started crashing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Xcode. Also, recheck your storyboard to make sure the label declaration is linked to the storyboard visual object...

Comment: I reverted my code to the one that was working (reverting failed attempts at fixing), and it seems like it's a simulator issue...works fine on my devices.

Comment: I've had cases where code worked on simulators running specific iOS versions but not others (i.e, it worked on iOS8 but not iOS7